# How to put a ListView title in an Android bubble

Tags: android, android-listview, android-xml

I need to place `the date as the title of a Listview` but `inside a bubble`, someone could tell me how to do it.

Here is the code to place the `date as a title:`

```
readFechaActual();
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText(stringDate);
listView.addHeaderView(textView);
```

With this code I get this:

[image]

But what I need a title like this:

[image]

Here is the file to create the bubble: `drawable/time_message.xml:`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/SALMON" />
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner_white"
  >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_search_what"
        style="@style/gray_12_l"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

align this layout in center

round_corner_white

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="@color/blue" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/_20sdp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/_20sdp" />
</shape>
```